# Graphical layout not coming in Eclipse why?

Tags: android, eclipse

While I open a layout and click in Graphical tab it won't display anything. Can it be fixed [image: screen shoot here]

Any help please..

Comment: It will be so trivial but have you tried closing and opening eclipse again? In addition to these, close all the inner windows and clean your project.

Comment: yes I did 4-5 times but nothing is going good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your layout xml file and select **Open With -> Android Layout Editor**. It will force eclipse to open file in android's layout editor mode

Comment: Hello Waqas I tried it still won't work. It shows No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document. Now what to do please I'm new to Android as well eclipse. Thanks for your valuable time to help me.

Comment: update your Android Development Toolkit, i guess the newer version (16.0.1) should fix this issue